# Why are all of the nodes that I add to different lists ends up in one list?

Tags: java, list, nodes

I have two classes, RectNode and RectList. The assignment is to create a list of rectangles (with another class called RectangleA). When I use the tester it seems like all of the nodes are added to the all of lists, even tho I create different lists. For example, the tester creates two lists: `rL1` and `rL2`. Then it adds one rectangle to the 1st list, and one to the 2nd. The problem is that when I run the tester and prints both lists with a `toString()` method I created, it shows that both rectangles are in both of the lists. Can anyone help me find the problem?
**When running test:**
[image: 1]

rL1: The list has 2 rectangles.

1. Width=5 Height=7 PointSW=(0,0)
2. Width=3 Height=8 PointSW=(0,0)

rL2: The list has 2 rectangles.

1. Width=5 Height=7 PointSW=(0,0)
2. Width=3 Height=8 PointSW=(0,0)

**classes:**

```
public class RectList
{
    private static RectNode _head;
    public RectList(){
        _head = null;
    }
    public static void addRect(RectangleA r){
        if(empty()){
            _head = new RectNode(r);
        }else{
            boolean isThereRectangle = false;
            RectNode ptr = _head;
            while(ptr.getNext() != null){
                if(ptr.getRect().equals(r)){
                    isThereRectangle = true;
                }
                ptr = ptr.getNext();
            }
            if(ptr.getRect().equals(r)){
                isThereRectangle = true;
            }
            if(isThereRectangle == false){
                ptr.setNext(new RectNode(r));
            }
        }
    }
    public String toString(){
        String list = "";
        int counter = 0;
        if(!empty()){
            RectNode ptr = _head;
            while(ptr != null){
                counter++;
                list += (counter + ". " + ptr.getRect().toString() + "\r\n");
                ptr = ptr.getNext();
            }
        }
        return ("The list has " + counter + " rectangles." + "\r\n" + list);
        
    }
}
public class RectNode
{
    private RectangleA _rect;
    private RectNode _next;
    public RectNode(RectangleA r){
        _rect = r;
        _next = null;
    }
    public RectNode(RectangleA r, RectNode n) {
        _rect = r;
        _next = n;
    }
    public RectNode(RectNode r){
        _rect = r._rect;
        _next = r._next;
    }
    public RectangleA getRect(){
        return new RectangleA(_rect);
    }
    public RectNode getNext(){
        return _next;
    }
    public void setRect(RectangleA r){
        _rect = new RectangleA(r);
    }
    public void setNext(RectNode next){
        _next = next;
    }
}

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RectList rL1 = new RectList();
        RectList rL2 = new RectList();
        RectangleA r1 = new RectangleA(5, 7);
        RectangleA r2 = new RectangleA(3, 8);
        rL1.addRect(r1);
        rL2.addRect(r2);
        System.out.println("rL1: " + rL1.toString() +"\nrL2: " + rL2.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: `private static RectNode _head` - have a look at that line again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `_head` variable is a `static` property of the `RectList` class . `static` members have the same value in all occurrences of the class.
so when you do `rL1.addRect(r1);` `rL2` also get `r1` as it's head.
then you do `rL2.addrect(r2)` and it adds `r2` to the reference of the head, which is the same head of both objects (because the head is the static variable).

you can just remove the `static` keyword and it should do the trick.